# sorting numerically by first row

Tags: bash, macos, sorting, carriage-return, numerical

I have a file with almost 900 lines in excel that I've saved as a tab deliminated .txt file. I'd like to sort the text file by the numbers given in the first column (they range between 0 and 2250). The other columns are both numbers and letters of varying length eg.

myfile.txt:

```
0251  abcd 1234,24 bcde
2240  efgh 2345,98 ikgpppm
0001  lkjsi 879,09 ikol
```

I've tried

```
sort -k1 -n myfile.txt > myfile_num.txt
```

but I just get an identical file with new name. I'd like to get:

myfile_num.txt

```
0001  lkjsi 879,09 ikol 
0251  abcd 1234,24 bcde
2240  efgh 2345,98 ikgpppm
```

What am I doing wrong? I'm guessing that it's quite simple, but I'd appreciate any help I can get! I only know a little bash scripting, so it'd be nice if the script is a very simple one-liner that I can understand :)

Thanks :)

Comment: I ran it on my machine and it's working as it supposed to. Can you try with: `sort -k1 -h myfile.txt > myfile_num.txt` ?

Comment: can you try with `sort -k1 -t\t` ? Problem with pasting tab-separated files here is that tabs are converted into spaces. Should work, though, because here numerical=string because of the zeros.

Comment: try `sort` without any options.

Comment: Upload your file somewhere and post link here.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/qtbgm4a76bu04vk/myfile.txt?dl=0

Comment: I can't get the -h to work. nor the -t\t...

Comment: @Cyrus: I uploaded a link to the text file :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this to convert old Mac OS carriage return to newline:

```
tr '\r' '\n' < myfile.txt | sort
```

Comment: Would it be possible for you to help me with this also? In the following document Proteins.txt I want to do the same, but it doesn't work. It only gives me the first 200 lines output and terminal writes "tr: Illegal byte sequence"...  https://www.dropbox.com/s/umzx64c5ix90l3y/Proteins.txt?dl=0

Comment: I looked around and saw that the tr command might work better with .csv but it doesn't do anything different and still gives me the "tr: illegal byt sequence" when I use the command you suggestion on my new linked file... any other suggestions for using the command on my big file?

Comment: I suggest to start a new question wih this Non-ISO extended-ASCII file.

Comment: I'll do so tomorrow. I can't post more than one question every 90 minutes... But thanks for helping me out :)

Comment: Please check my python solution. Works fine here, and I'm 100% sure it will work fine on MacOSX too.

Comment: @Ditte: **If** you start a new question, I suggest to ask at [Super User](http://superuser.com/tour).

Answer (score 0):

As stated [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/141420/tr-complains-of-illegal-byte-sequence) you can have problems with this (and in the other pseudo-follow-up-duplicate [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39058356/bash-sort-numerical-osx) you asked, yes, you did)

```
tr '\r' '\n' < myfile.txt | sort -n
```

It works fine here on MSYS but on some platforms you may have to add:

```
export LC_CTYPE=C
```

or `tr` will consider the file as a text file, and probably will tag it as corrupt after having reached the max line limit.

Obviously I could not test it, but I'm confident it will solve the problem given what I read on the linked answer.

Comment: so do I use the command :  tr '\r' '\n' < myfile.txt | sort -n export LC_CTYPE=C > myfile_num.txt to save it?

Comment: If I use "LC_CTYPE=C tr '\r' '\n' < myfile.txt | sort -n > Myfile_num.txt" I get only one row of  output data...

Answer (score 0):

A python approach (python 2 & 3 compatible), immune to all shell problems. Works great, and portable. I noticed that the input file has some '0x8C' chars (exotic dots), probably confusing `tr` command.
That is handled properly below:

```
import csv,sys

# read the file as binary, as it is not really text
with open("Proteins.txt","rb") as f:
    data = bytearray(f.read())
    # replace 0x8c char by classical dots
    for i,c in enumerate(data):
        if c>0x7F: # non-ascii: replace by dot
            data[i] = ord(".")

    # convert to list of ASCII strings (split using the old MAC separator)
    lines = "".join(map(chr,data)).split("\r")

    # treat our lines as input for CSV reader
    cr = csv.reader(lines,delimiter='\t',quotechar='"')

    # read all the lines in a list    
    rows = list(cr)
    # perform the sort (tricky)
    # on first row, numerical, removing the leading 0 which is illegal
    # in python 3, and if not numerical, put it at the top

    rows = sorted(rows,key=lambda x : x[0].isdigit() and int(x[0].strip("0")))

# write back the file as a nice, legal, ASCII tsv file

if sys.version_info < (3,):
    f = open("Proteins_sorted_2.txt","wb")
else:
    f = open("Proteins_sorted_2.txt","w",newline='')

cw = csv.writer(f,delimiter='\t',quotechar='"')
cw.writerows(rows)
f.close()
```

Comment: ahh... I only have python 2.7 on my osx :(