# bash sort numerical osx

Tags: bash, macos, sorting, numerical

This is sort of a re-post/development of a question:

I've tried to use the command

```
  tr '\r' '\n' < myfile.txt | sort > myfile_num.txt
```

to a file containing about 900 lines of data, that I want to sort numerically. It seems like others are able to get the right output file with all lines included (as below) but I'm not. Instead I get "tr: illegal byte sequence"

myfile.txt

```
    0251  abcd 1234,24 bcde
    2240  efgh 2345,98 ikgpppm
    0001  lkjsi 879,09 ikol
```

I'd like to get:

myfile_num.txt

```
0001  lkjsi 879,09 ikol 
0251  abcd 1234,24 bcde
2240  efgh 2345,98 ikgpppm
```

Am I doing something wrong with the rest of the file? Am I saving it wrongly?

Thanks :)

Comment: the file is here: dropbox.com/s/umzx64c5ix90l3y/Proteins.txt?dl=0

Comment: seems to work fine here. Can you point out one of unexepected results here?

Comment: proteins.txt contains almost 900 lines, the proteins_num.txt has only 200 lines and terminal says "tr: Illegal byte sequence"

Comment: My sorted file has 835 lines: check here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/yohducmd4gaan8k/Protsort.txt?dl=0

Comment: That's really strange... Your file looks exactly like what I'd want for output. I must be doing something wrong in the terminal then

Comment: no, I have posted another answer (more a complement) in the other question (this one is marked as duplicate now)